# Shape formatting - Lock shape size, but still be able to move shape

Tags: excel

Need some help with shape formatting.

Seems like there must be an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to lock the size of the blue circles shown below, but still want to be able to move them.

The purpose of the blue circles is to drag and drop into the bullseye target during robot leveling checks.
I just don't want to allow the user to change the size of the blue circle when selecting it and placing it in the bullseye target.

[image: Excel snip]

Answer (score 0):

Use Line (shape) instead of a circle.

Step :

Insert (a very short) line.

> set weight (around 5-6 pt)
> set Begin Arrow Type : Round
> The will look like a circle. ( :
> Done.

p/s : by defining a very short line there is no 'radius' parameter.

Comment: Hi phidot, Thank you for your response. That method results in the same outcome I currently have. Even if I use line shape and change as you suggested, the user can still adjust the shape after I protect the worksheet. The end result I am looking for is to completely lock any shape formatting and only allow user to move shape around by drag/drop.

Comment: afaik, excel only offers to lock cell & its content. Shape is coordinate locked, not cell.